# Create a dynamically dimensioned Array or List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I want to create an Array or a List with N-Dimensions.

Is there a way to do this without having a Method for each possible dimension:

```
private ____ createArray(int dimensions, int[] lengths)
{
    // declare array with dimensions from variable dimensions
    // set length of first dimension to lengths[0]
    // set length of second dimension to lengths[1]
    // [...] 
    // return array
}
```

And not like this

```
private int[][][] create3DArray(int[] lengths)
{
    int[][][] array = new int[lengths[0]][][];

    int[] newLengths = new int[lengths.Count - 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < lengths.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        newLengths[i] = lengths[i + 1];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < lengths[0]; i++)
    {
        array[i] = create2DArray(newLengths);
    }

    return array;
}

private int[][] create2DArray(int[] lengths)
{
    int[][] array = new int[lengths[0]][];

    for(int i = 0; i < lengths.Count; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new int[lengths[1]];
    }

    return array;
}
```

If I have to do it like this, I need to have a method for every possible (let's ignore the fact that it may not make sense to have an array with N-Dimensions) amount of dimensions.

Comment: `List` "dimension" is `flexible` enough I think, you may just need to initialize its value?

Comment: There is the `Array.CreateInstance` method, but it creates a multi-dimensional array and not a jagged array like you want.

Comment: @Ian How would I create a List, which I could use like a 4D-Array? Like list[i][j][k][l] = // fill with some random number

Comment: Checkout my example, is that what you want?

Comment: @Dirk Array.CreateInstance seems like it could do what i want. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can create a **list of lists**:

```
var myList = new List<List<int>>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    var localList = new List<int>();
    myList.Add(localList);
}
```

Comment: And if I want the List to contain a List which contains a List [...] (as many times as i want) and then return that list?

Answer (score 1):

You could create like this using `Enumerable.Repeat` as many levels as you want:

```
int x = 5, y = 6, z = 7;
List<List<List<int>>> list3D = Enumerable.Repeat<List<List<int>>>(
    new List<List<int>>(
        Enumerable.Repeat<List<int>>(
            new List<int>(
                    Enumerable.Repeat<int>(0, z)
                    ), y)
        ), x
    ).ToList();
}
```

In the example above you create 3D lists with initial value of 0 and initial size of 5x6x7

Comment: This gets in the right direction. But if i want to make it with N-Dimensions? Instead of 3?

Comment: Then just add another level. Notice that the pattern is simply `Enumerable.Repeat`

Comment: ...but i have to add another level if i want more dimensions, which is exactly what i don't want.

Comment: I get what you mean, in that case you need to have a recursive call. Makes a generic method, then wrap the previous list in a list

Comment: I think maybe I am to dumb for generic methods... If you could post working code - I would be more than happy to accept it as answer.

Comment: This method has a serious flaw in that the inner lists are all identical references. If you set `list3D[0][1][2] = 4` then all `list3D[x][y][2] == 4`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

Make an int array of dimensions. From there, you can create a conditional var declaration. The only trick is that you need to make explicit the conversion to (Array)